# How can I play mp3 from recyclerview using Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity, android-recyclerview

so I am trying to play an audio file from the raw folder by using a button that found in recyclerview but I tried everything and nothing seems to work for me
can you please help me and thanks in advance

P.C. this is a sample just to Know how to add an audio file in a recyclerview hopefully I will be adding more so if you have any tutorials on to add progress bar, image buttons... etc in recyclerview please share it with me

here is my progress so far

**my Recyclerview Adater**

```
class shaikh( val context: Context, val names: ArrayList<String>, val images: ArrayList<Int>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

private  var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val callXml = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.quranvoice,parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(callXml)
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return names.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.itemView.ShaikhName.text = names.get(position)
    holder.itemView.Shaikh.setImageResource(images.get(position))
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
      when(position){
          0->{
              holder.itemView.voice.setOnClickListener {
                  if (mediaPlayer != null){
                      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.abdelbasset)
                      mediaPlayer?.start()
                  }

              }

          }
          1->{
              Toast.makeText(context,"الشيخ ناصر",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

          }
      }
    }
}



}

public class ViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    fun ViewHolder( ){
    }
}
```

**my Activity**

```
 var texts: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
var images : ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()

  // nothing is in here except the onCreate method 

val Adapter = shaikh(this, texts, images)
   QuranVoice.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, true)
   QuranVoice.setHasFixedSize(true)
   QuranVoice.setAdapter( Adapter)
   QuranVoice.addOnScrollListener(CenterScrollListener())
   loadData()

  private fun loadData() {
    texts.add("الشيخ عبدالباسط عبدالصمد - رحمه الله-")
    images.add(R.drawable.abdelbasset_abdessamad)


    texts.add("الشيخ خالد مغمسي")
    images.add(R.drawable.ic_esha_time)
    texts.add("الشيخ خالد مغمسي")
    images.add(R.drawable.ic_dhur_time)

}
```